# I need to use the data from first picture to draw cylinder,put two cylinders point B is not coincide(like second picture)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

**I need to use the data from first picture to draw cylinder,put two cylinders point B is not coincide(like second picture) ** [image]

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10,151.02648774304458, 20, 1, false); 
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.set(1,75.5,1);

scene.add(mesh);

var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }); 
var geometry1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10,158.8741640418605, 20, 1, false); 
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1); 
mesh1.position.set(-30,217,32.5);
mesh1.rotation.set(2,151,2);


scene.add(mesh1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the red cylinder to a [`Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group). Set the position in that way, that the bottom of the cylinder is at (0, 0, 0). Set the position of the group in that way, that it's origin is at the top of the black cylinder.
Finally you have to rotate the group:

```
let height = 151.02648774304458;
let height1 = 158.8741640418605;

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10, height, 20, 1, false); 
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.set(1, 75.5, 1);

scene.add(mesh);

var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }); 
var geometry1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10, height1, 20, 1, false); 
var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1); 
mesh1.position.set(0, height1/2, 0);

group = new THREE.Group();
group.position.set(mesh.position.x, mesh.position.y + height/2, mesh.position.z);
group.add(mesh1);

group.rotation.set(...);

scene.add(group);
```

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      canvas: my_canvas,
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    //container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 200, -400);
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    
    window.onresize = function() {
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
    
    createModel();

  }

  var group;
  function createModel() {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#ff0000'});
    var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#000000'});

    let height = 151.02648774304458;
    let height1 = 158.8741640418605;

    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10, height, 20, 1, false); 
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(1, 75.5, 1);

    scene.add(mesh);

    var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 }); 
    var geometry1 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(10, 10, height1, 20, 1, false); 
    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1); 
    mesh1.position.set(0, height1/2, 0);

    group = new THREE.Group();
    group.position.set(mesh.position.x, mesh.position.y + height/2, mesh.position.z);
    group.add(mesh1);

    //group.rotation.set(2, 151, 2);

    scene.add(group);
  }

  var rotate = 0.0;
  function animate() {
  
    group.rotation.set(0, 0, rotate);
    rotate += 0.01;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"><canvas id="my_canvas"> </canvas></div>
```

---

To set a specific rotation by a specific vector, I recommend to set the rotation by a [`.setRotationFromQuaternion`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion).
The [`Quaternion`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Quaternion) defines how to rotate from the upwards direction (0, 1, 0) to the target direction. The Target direction is the vector form the joint to the endpoint of the upper cylinder (-62-1, 283-151, 61-1):

For instance:

```js
let upVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
let targetVector = new THREE.Vector3(-62 - 1, 283 - height, 61 - 1);
let quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(
    upVector, targetVector.normalize());
group.setRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely @Rabbid76                Now I know how to coincide two point . Can you provided more details about how to let the red cylinder conform the vector BC ?

Comment: @張秝榕 So you want to know the proper rotation angles (`group.rotation.set(,...)`) for your special use case?

Comment: Yes. @Rabbid76 Can you tell me ? If you know. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so match  your answer . Now I have an idea. I think I know how to do it.

Comment: @張秝榕 I've extended the answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76Thank you so so so match. I think I can probably understand. Thank you ! !